# Why can't I create new accounts on testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, testnets

So I've set up a new testnet using

```
geth --identity "NNode" --genesis /home/test/Documents/Ethereum/genesis.json --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "/home/test/Documents/Ethereum/chain" --port "30303" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 1900 --nat "any" console'
```

This is the output:

```
I0207 11:54:28.222377 cmd/utils/flags.go:532] WARNING: No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
I0207 11:54:28.222762 ethdb/database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/test/Documents/Ethereum/chain/chaindata
I0207 11:54:28.228739 ethdb/database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/test/Documents/Ethereum/chain/dapp
I0207 11:54:28.231963 eth/backend.go:163] Protocol Versions: [63 62 61], Network Id: 1900
I0207 11:54:28.233421 core/genesis.go:91] Genesis block already in chain. Writing canonical number
I0207 11:54:28.233854 eth/backend.go:171] Successfully wrote custom genesis block: 6650a0ac6c5e805475e7ca48eae5df0e32a2147a154bb2222731c770ddb5c158
I0207 11:54:28.234071 eth/backend.go:191] Blockchain DB Version: 3
I0207 11:54:28.234998 core/blockchain.go:210] Last header: #0 [6650a0ac…] TD=1024
I0207 11:54:28.235095 core/blockchain.go:211] Last block: #0 [6650a0ac…] TD=1024
I0207 11:54:28.235116 core/blockchain.go:212] Fast block: #0 [6650a0ac…] TD=1024
I0207 11:54:28.235644 p2p/server.go:311] Starting Server
I0207 11:54:28.236199 eth/backend.go:415] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG ON (ethash dir: /home/test/.ethash)
I0207 11:54:28.236922 p2p/server.go:555] Listening on [::]:30303
I0207 11:54:28.237359 eth/backend.go:422] checking DAG (ethash dir: /home/test/.ethash)
I0207 11:54:28.241377 cmd/utils/flags.go:778] Start IPC server on /home/test/Documents/Ethereum/chain/geth.ipc
instance: Geth/v1.4.0-unstable/linux/go1.5.1/NNode
coinbase: [object Object]
at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 12:00:00 NZST)
 datadir: /home/test/Documents/Ethereum/chain
>
```

Creating new account

```
> personal.newAccount('somepassword')
New account doesn't expect argument(s), you will be prompted for a password
false
> personal.listAccounts
{
  code: -32000,
  message: "no keys in store"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use your password as an argument to `personal.newAccount`.

Just use `personal.newAccount()`, then it will prompt for a password. Note that there should be nothing between the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You don't enter the password on the command line anymore:

```
> personal.newAccount("Test")
New account doesn't expect argument(s), you will be prompted for a password
false
```

Instead, run the method without any argument and it will prompt you for a passphrase:

```
> personal.newAccount()
Passphrase: Test
Repeat passphrase: Test
"0x0c2f2f7ef02b7d50f50a7cd73e7f935804a88916"
> personal.listAccounts
["0x0c2f2f7ef02b7d50f50a7cd73e7f935804a88916"]
```

The error output explicitly mentions that by the way :)